# Integration limits problem

Tags: integration, limits

Here is a part of a problem I have a hard time with:

> Let $$f(x)= 10e^{-0.201x}+3$$
>
> Let $$g(x)= -x^2+12x-24$$
>
> Find the area enclosed by the graphs of f and g

Here is the answer as explained by the teacher:

> Finding limits $3.8953$ and $8.6940$
>
> Evidence of integrating and subtracting functions
>
> Correct expression is....

And then he integrates both the functions with these two limits above.
He finds an area of $19.5$.

But how did he find these two limits in the first place?

Thanks.

Comment: You have to intersect the curves, in other words , solve $f(x)=g(x)$

Comment: Are you sure about the expression for the functions?

Comment: Well, I'm sure because it's the answer as given by the teacher. Problem is I don't know how to write a full integration here to show the final expression.
Basically, he integrates the two functions between these two limits.
This seems ok but finding these two limits is not trivial to me.

Comment: @gimusi why do you think so?

Comment: @peter: ok. if I consider g(x)=f(x), I get this final result:  -2,01= ln (-(x/10)^2+1,2x-2,7).
And then, I'm stuck again...

Comment: @BachirMessaouri You can find the solutions only numerically (or perhaps with the Lambert-W-function). The exercise should be correct because the given numbers are actually roots of $f(x)-g(x)$

Comment: @BachirMessaouri Here's a tutorial for [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). I have edited the first line for you; you can edit the rest yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much Toby

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici My guess, thank you nevertheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the area enclosed you need the limits and the limits are found by finding the points where the two functions intersect; this is done by setting $f(x) =g(x)$

$f(x) = 10e^{-0.201 x}+3$

$g(x) = -x^2+12x-24$

$f(x) =g(x) \implies 10e^{-0.201x}+3 = -x^2+12x-24$

$\implies 10e^{-0.201x} = -x^2+12x-27$

This cannot be solved by algebraic manipulations, but you can find the values using numerical methods such as [Newtons method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method)

define $h(x)=10e^{-0.201x}+x^2-12x+27$

$x_1 = x_0-\frac{h(x_0)}{h'(x_0)}$

choosing $4$ as the initial guess and successive iterations 
 gets us;

$x_1 = 4 - \frac{h(4)}{h'(4)} = 4- \frac{-0.524648}{-4.899546} = 3.892$

$x_2 = 3.892 = \frac{h(3.892)}{h'(3.892)} = 3.892+0.003355 = 3.8953$

You could go for more iterations but i think this level of approximation is good enough.

To find the other root set $x_0$ equal to another guess, since you've said the root lies at $8.6940$ I'll let $x_0 =9$

$x_1 = 9-\frac{h(9)}{h'(9)}= 9-0.28883= 8.71117$

$x_2 = 8.71117-\frac{h(8.71117)}{h'(8.7117)}= 8.71117-0.017058 =8.694112$

hence you've found your other root.

So the integral is $\displaystyle\int_{3.8953}^{8.694112}(-x^2+12x-24-10e^{-0.201 x}-3)\,dx $

The above integral evaluates to $19.4914$ $\quad\bigg[$found by [Wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_%7B3.8953%7D%5E%7B8.694112%7D(-x%5E2%2B12x-24)-(10e%5E%7B-0.201%20x%7D%2B3))%5C,dx)$\bigg]$

EDIT:

Note that I am using a calculator to do the calculations . If calculators are not allowed in your classes , then please  do not go for this method.

Comment: Thank you. I'm glad to see that finding the limits is not trivial because the short explanation from the teacher isn't helping. So I believe the calculator should be used. FYI, I'm not the student but the relative of a student.

Answer (score 2):

The limits are found as the intersections of the two curves, a decaying exponential and a downward parabola. There will be no closed-form of the roots and you need to use numerical methods.

To obtain good starting estimates, you can replace the exponential (blue) by its second order development (magenta), to obtain a quadratic approximation. For convenience we will shift the origin of the coordinates to the vertex of the parabola, at $x=6$. Now with $z=x-6$,

$$-z^2+12=10e^{-0.203(z+6)}=10e^{-1.218}e^{-0.203z}+3\\
\approx10e^{-1.218}(1-0.203z+0.0206045z^2)+3.$$

Solving the quadratic equation, we find

$$x=z+6=3.879932\text{ or }x=8.68608.$$

[image]

Then you can refine with Newton.

Answer (score 0):

To find the intersection points, you have to solve for $x$, $f(x)=g(x)$ which, by the end, means that you are looking for the zeros of function
$$h(x)=10\, e^{-201 x/1000}+x^2-12 x+27$$ The derivative
$$h'(x)=2 x-\frac{201}{100} e^{-201 x/1000}-12$$ cancels at 
$$x_*=6+\frac{1000}{201} W\left(\frac{40401}{200000} e^{-603/500}\right)$$ where appears [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). Since the argument is quite small $(\approx0.0604788)$, you can easily evaluate the result using the very first terms of the series expansion
$$W(t)=t-t^2+\frac{3 t^3}{2}-\frac{8 t^4}{3}+\frac{125 t^5}{24}+O\left(t^6\right)$$ and get $x_* \approx 6.28418$.

Now, make a Taylor series at $x=x_*$; since the first derivative is $0$ at $x=x_*$, you have 
$$h(x)=h(x_*)+\frac 12 h''(x_*)(x-x_*)^2+O\left((x-x_*)^3\right)$$ with
$$h''(x)=2+\frac{40401 }{100000}\,e^{-201 x/1000}$$ Ignoring the higher order terms and solving the quadratic gives, as *approximation*,
$$x_1=3.88369 \qquad \text{and} \qquad x_2=8.68468$$
Now, let us start Newton iterations with these  as starting values. The iterates would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_1^{(n)} \\
 0 & 3.883687134 \\
 1 & 3.895328641 \\
 2 & 3.895357513
\end{array}
\right)$$ and
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_2^{(n)} \\
 0 & 8.684680824 \\
 1 & 8.694070586 \\
 2 & 8.694052468
\end{array}
\right)$$ which are the solutions for ten significant figures.